# Why am i not able to regenerate a new game board after user respond yes to if the want to restart?

Tags: java

```
https://cse.sc.edu/~shephejj/csce146/Homework/Homework01.html

import java.util.*;
public class MineSweep {
    enum  Spaces{Empty,Player,Cone,Mine}
    public static final int Board_Size=10;
    public final static double Percent_Mine = 0.1;

    public static void main(String[]arg){
        Spaces[][] Board= new Spaces[Board_Size][Board_Size];//Creates new multidimensional array.
        int numOfMoves=0;
        int positionX=0;
        int positionY=0;
        boolean isOver=false;
        boolean isDead = false;
        Random r= new Random();
        //Random Places the cone on the GameBoard.
        int coneX=r.nextInt(Board_Size);
        int coneY=r.nextInt(Board_Size);
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++){
            for(int j =0; j<Board[1].length;j++){
                Board[i][j]=Spaces.Empty;
                    }
                }
        Board[positionX][positionY]= Spaces.Player;
        Board[coneX][coneY]=Spaces.Cone;
        System.out.println("Welcoem to Mine Walker. Get the ice cream cone and avoid the Mines.");

        int mines = (int)(Board_Size*Board_Size*Percent_Mine);
        do
        {
            int x = r.nextInt(Board_Size-1)+1;
            int y =r.nextInt(Board_Size-1)+1;
            //Places mines in random spots
            if (Board[x][y]== Spaces.Empty)
            {
            Board[x][y]=Spaces.Mine;
            mines--;
            }
        }
        while(mines>0);
        if(isDead==true){
        Board=generateBoard();
        }else{

            while(isOver==false)
                {
                for(int y=0;y<Board.length;y++)
                {
                    for(int x=0;x<Board[y].length;x++)
                    {
                        switch(Board[x][y])
                        {
                            case Empty:
                                System.out.print("_");
                                break;
                            case Player:
                                System.out.print("X");
                                break;
                            case Mine:
                                System.out.print("!");
                                break;
                            case Cone:
                                System.out.print("^");
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.print("?");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("Enter either -1,0,1 to move in the X or 9 to quit");

                int directionX = Scan.nextInt();

                if(directionX==9)
                {
                    System.out.println("Game Over");
                    System.exit(0);

                    }
                System.out.println("Enter either -1,0,1 to move in th Y");
                int directionY= Scan.nextInt();

                if(directionX<-1 || directionX>1){
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input X");
                    directionX=0;
                }
                if(directionY <-1 || directionY>1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input Y");
                    directionY = 0;
                }

                Board[positionX][positionY] = Spaces.Empty;
                positionX+=directionX;
                positionY+=directionY;

                if(positionX < 0)
                {
                    positionX = 0;
                }
                else if(positionX>Board_Size-1)
                {
                    positionX = Board_Size-1;
                }
                if(positionY < 0)
                {
                    positionY = 0;
                }
                else if(positionY> Board_Size-1)
                {
                    positionY = Board_Size-1;
                }
                String retry;
                if(Board[positionX][positionY]==Spaces.Mine)
                {           
                    isDead=true;
                    System.out.println("Boom! Dead!");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");  
                    retry = scan2.nextLine();
                    if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                    {

                            isOver = false;  
                            generateBoard();
                    }
                    else if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        System.exit(0); 
                    }
                }
                if(Board[positionX][positionY]==Spaces.Cone)
                {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
                }
                Board[positionX][positionY] = Spaces.Player;  
            }
        }
    }


    public static Spaces[][] generateBoard(){
        int positionX=0;
        int positionY=0;
        Random r= new Random();
        //Random Places the cone on the GameBoard.
        int coneX=r.nextInt(Board_Size);
        int coneY=r.nextInt(Board_Size);
        Spaces[][] Board= new Spaces[Board_Size][Board_Size];
     for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++){
            for(int j =0; j<Board[1].length;j++){
                Board[i][j]=Spaces.Empty;
                    }
                }
        Board[positionX][positionY]= Spaces.Player;
        Board[coneX][coneY]=Spaces.Cone;
        System.out.println("Welcoem to Mine Walker. Get the ice cream cone and avoid the Mines.");

        int mines = (int)(Board_Size*Board_Size*Percent_Mine);
        do
        {
            int x = r.nextInt(Board_Size-1)+1;
            int y =r.nextInt(Board_Size-1)+1;
            //Places mines in random spots
            if (Board[x][y]== Spaces.Empty)
            {
            Board[x][y]=Spaces.Mine;
            mines--;
            }
        }
        while(mines>0);
        return Board;
    }
}
```

In the code is above.Everything works, i'm just unable to create a new game board.I create a method called "generateboard()" and I call that method if "isDead= true" and user responds yes to if they want to retry.Please Help !

Comment: try stepping though your code with a debugger

Comment: You should break this down into classes and/or methods. `play()` a `Game`, when it's over `play()` another if they want. `do { new Game.play(); } while (isPlaying);`

Answer (score 0):

First of, you should really try to clean up your code a bit. It has some duplication and it is kinda hard to read. That said, I think your problem lies with this piece of code:

```
if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
{
    isOver = false;  
    generateBoard();
}
```

You are generating a new board, but you are not telling your program to use it. Change `generateBoard()` to `Board = generateBoard();`. Also you forget to reset your players position to 0,0.

Now I would like to give you some pointers on how you could clean up your program. The first part of your main method is basically a copy paste of your generate board method, this means that you could instead reuse that method to initialize the board.

After generating your board, the first if statement `if (isDead == true)` will never be true, because you just set `isDead = false`.  Just do away with this if statement. This actually makes your isDead variable unused, because you don't use it otherwise.

You probably want to either return the starting position of the player from the generateBoard method, or take the starting position as arguments to the method in order to know where the position of the player is. In your example your player always starts at 0,0, but one could imagine that you would want to change that some time.

A couple of things to note:
In Java, variables usually start with a lower case letter (use "board" instead of "Board").
Enums in Java are usually all UPPER CASE (EMPTY instead of Empty etc.).
You don't need to use `== false` or `==true` on boolean values, you could simply write: `if (isDead)`.

You could also do with dividing your code into methods, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you. Also, you don't actually do anything when a player wins in the game.